# Aligning "key value comment" file type using emacs

Tags: regex, emacs, alignment

How is it possible to use the `align` emacs command to align a file structured as follow?

```
 key.name1   "his value 1";  # the comment
 key.name2      "his other value";
 otherkey.id    10;  # comment
 key.without.other ; # comment
 key2.without.other true;             # comment
```

I am using `conf-mode` under emacs 25.

The columns are encoded as follows:

- First column (key) is a string without spaces,
- Second column (value) arrives until the semicolon,
- Third column (comment) is not always present and starts with `#`".

Result should be

```
 key.name1         "his value 1";     # the comment
 key.name2         "his other value"; 
 otherkey.id       10;                # comment
 key.without.other ;                  # comment
 key2.without.other true;             # comment
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you could describe how you wish to see this aligned.

By selecting these lines and running `align-regexp` with a prefix argument, I was able to use the following regexp to align all of these fields by looking for more than one consecutive spaces.  This is probably not the best solution but it works for this sample data.

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd>`align-regexp`<kbd>RET</kbd>`\(\s-\s-+\)`<kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

Result:

```
 key.name1   "his value 1"     # the comment
 key.name2   "his other value" # another comment
 otherkey.id 10                # comment
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edited the question to be more specific